# Crash Xen hypervisor on purpose

Tags: linux-kernel, centos, xen, hypervisor

I am wondering if there is any way I can crash the Xen hypervisor on purpose? I installed the Xen with CentOS 5.5, and I am able to crash the Domain 0 (CentOS 5.5) with echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger. Can I do such kind of crash to Xen hypervisor?

Thanks for any inputs!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to crash the Dom0 with sysrq, you are already crashing Xen management domain which eventually kills Xen.